# (Jax) Reshape pytree containing arrays of different shapes

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, treemap, jax

I have a pytree containing arrays that have different shapes, for example it contains:

- `observations` of shape `(5, 3, 250, 23)`
- `dones` of shape `(5, 3, 250)`

I want to reshape my pytree so that the first two dimensions are merged, which would give something like `(15, 250, ...)` for every object in my pytree.

I usually use `tree_map` to work on my pytrees but this time I struggle to make it work, I tried:

```
jax.tree_map(lambda x: jnp.reshape(x, newshape=(15, -1)), my_pytree)
```

it works well for `dones` but it merges the last dimensions for `observations`, leading to an array of shape `(15, 5750)` (and I'd want it to be `(15, 250, 23)` here).

Note: I cannot modify the definition of my pytree, I have to work with this structure.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the post it was kind of trivial. I post the answer just in case:

```
jax.tree_map(lambda x: jnp.reshape(x, newshape=(15, *x.shape[2:])),my_pytree)
```